# RxJS: Auto (dis)connect on (un)subscribe with Websockets and Stomp

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, reactivex, reactive

I'm building a litte RxJS Wrapper for Stomp over Websockets, which already works.

But now I had the idea of a really cool feature, that may (hopefully - correct me if I'm wrong) be easily done using RxJS.

### Current behavior:

```
myStompWrapper.configure("/stomp_endpoint");
myStompWrapper.connect();      // onSuccess: set state to CONNECTED

// state (Observable) can be DISCONNECTED or CONNECTED
var subscription = myStompWrapper.getState()
    .filter(state => state == "CONNECTED")
    .flatMap(myStompWrapper.subscribeDestination("/foo"))
    .subscribe(msg => console.log(msg));

// ... and some time later:
subscription.unsubscribe();    // calls 'unsubscribe' for this stomp destination
myStompWrapper.disconnect();   // disconnects the stomp websocket connection
```

As you can see, I **must** wait for `state == "CONNECTED"` in order to subscribe to `subscribeDestination(..)`. Else I'd get an Error from the Stomp Library.

### The new behavior:

The next implementation should make things easier for the user. Here's what I imagine:

```
myStompWrapper.configure("/stomp_endpoint");

var subscription = myStompWrapper.subscribeDestination("/foo")
    .subscribe(msg => console.log(msg));

// ... and some time later:
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

**How it should work internally:**

1. `configure` can only be called while `DISCONNECTED`
2. when `subscribeDestination` is called, there are 2 possibilities:

   1. if `CONNECTED`: just subscribe to the destination
   2. if `DISCONNECTED`: first call `connect()`, then subscribe to the destination
3. when `unsubscribe` is called, there are 2 possibilities:

   1. if this was the last subscription: call `disconnect()`
   2. if this wasn't the last subscription: do nothing

I'm not yet sure how to get there, but that's why I ask this question here `;-)`

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT: more code, examples and explanations

When **configure()** is called while **not** disconnected it should throw an `Error`. But that's not a big deal.

**stompClient.connect(..)** is non-blocking. It has an `onSuccess` callback:

```
public connect() {
  stompClient.connect({}, this.onSuccess, this.errorHandler);
}

public onSuccess = () => {
  this.state.next(State.CONNECTED);
}
```

**observeDestination(..)** subscribes to a Stomp Message Channel (= destination) and returns an `Rx.Observable` which then can be used to unsubscribe from this Stomp Message Channel:

```
public observeDestination(destination: string) {
  return this.state
      .filter(state => state == State.CONNECTED)
      .flatMap(_ => Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
        let stompSubscription = this.client.subscribe(
            destination,
            message => observer.next(message),
            {}
        );

        return () => {
          stompSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      }));
}
```

**It can be used like this:**

```
myStompWrapper.configure("/stomp_endpoint");
myStompWrapper.connect();

myStompWrapper.observeDestination("/foo")
    .subscribe(..);

myStompWrapper.observeDestination("/bar")
    .subscribe(..);
```

**Now I'd like to get rid of `myStompWrapper.connect()`**. The code should automatically call `this.connect()` when the first one subscribes by calling `observeDestination(..).subscribe(..)` and it should call `this.disconnect()` when the last one called `unsubscribe()`.

**Example:**

```
myStompWrapper.configure("/stomp_endpoint");

let subscription1 = myStompWrapper.observeDestination("/foo")
    .subscribe(..); // execute connect(), because this
                    // is the first subscription

let subscription2 = myStompWrapper.observeDestination("/bar")
    .subscribe(..);

subscription2.unsubscribe();
subscription1.unsubscribe(); // execute disconnect(), because this 
                             // was the last subscription
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RxJS: Auto (dis)connect on (un)subscribe with Websockets and Stomp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602485/rxjs-auto-disconnect-on-unsubscribe-with-websockets-and-stomp)

I agree the code you are suggesting to tuck away into myStompWrapper will be happier in its new home.

I would still suggest to use a name like `observeDestination` rather than `subscribeDestination("/foo")` as you are not actually subscribing from that method but rather just completing your observable chain.

1. *`configure()` can only be called while `DISCONNECTED`*

   You do not specify here what should happen if it is called while not `DISCONNECTED`. As you do not seem to be returning any value here that you would use, I will assume that you intend to throw an exception if it has an inconvenient status. To keep track of such statuses, I would use a `BehaviourSubject` that starts with the initial value of `DISCONNECTED`. You likely will want to keep state within `observeDestination` to decide whether to throw an exception though
2. *if CONNECTED: just subscribe to the destination*

   *if DISCONNECTED: first call connect(), then subscribe to the destination*

   As I mentioned before, I think you will be happier if the subscription does not happen within `subscribeDestination("/foo")` but rather that you just build your observable chain. As you simply want to call `connect()` in some cases, I would simply use a `.do()` call within your observable chain that contains a condition on the state.
3. To make use of the rx-y logic, you likely want to call `disconnect()` as part of your observable unsubscribe and simply return a shared refcounted observable to start with. This way, each new subscriber does not recreate a new subscription, instead `.refCount()` will make a single subscription to the observable chain and `unsubscribe()` once there is no more subscribers downstream.

Assuming the messages are coming in as **this.observedData$** in `myStompWrapper` My suggested code as part of `myStompWrapper` would look something like this:

```
observeDestination() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
     var subscription = this.getState()
             .filter(state => state == "CONNECTED")
             .do(state => state ? this.connect() : Observable.of(true))
             .switchMap(this.observedData$)
             .refCount();
             .subscribe(value => {
               try {
                 subscriber.next(someCallback(value));
               } catch(err) {
                 subscriber.error(err);
               }
             },
             err => subscriber.error(err),
             () => subscriber.complete());

 return { unsubscribe() { this.disconnect(); subscription.unsubscribe(); } };
}
```

Because I am missing some of your code, I am allowing myself to not test my code. But hopefully it illustrates and presents the concepts I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess, I missed something within my description: You can call `observeDestination` multiple times: `observeDest("/foo"); observeDest("/bar");`. This will create 2 Stomp Subscriptions, each one returning an `Rx.Observable`. And the first Stomp subscription should trigger `this.connect()`, and the when unsubscribing from the last one, it should call `this.disconnect()`. I'll append more code, examples and explanations within my question in a few minutes.

Comment: refCount() will only subscribe once to its chain no matter how many subscribers it gets. What you will want to do is to separate the observable chain part from the subscription of clients. If you create a new question for it, I am happy to create a new answer. Just post it here. I do feel that your question and my answer will help others as is. Just post your special case as a new question please.